# Is there a way to set a start location for a text search in a browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, internet-explorer, search

I am doing a text search on a web page. Is there some way I can tell the browser, "Start searching from here", instead of searching from the top?

My present issue is that I am working through many items on a page. So I go to the page, find the first item, go do something about that, then I come back to the page to find the second. Okay, easy enough to press "next" to skip over the first one. But by the time I've done dozens, getting back to where I was is getting tedious. Yes, an alternative is to leave the page open, but then I don't see entries go away as I fix issues.

I came across this issue while working in IE but I'd be happy to hear an answer that works in Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be to copy the sentence from where you left in the text. When the user has selected some text in the page, Firefox will not search from the beginning of the page, it will select the next occurrence of the search pattern right after the selection.

A quick test: select with your cursor the "SELECT THIS WHOLE SENTENCE" phrase and then search for `ut`. You'll see Firefox will only select `aute` (because of the `ut` in the middle), even though it highlights all other instances of `ut`.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. **SELECT THIS WHOLE SENTENCE** Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
>   culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

So you can copy a long sentence that doesn't repeat itself in the page, this way when you search for this unique sentence in the page it will immediatelly bring you to where you left off in the text. After Firefox brought you to this point, just search for whatever else you want, it will start searching from this point onwards.